# Upload large files with Delphi Rest Components to Webserver

Tags: php, rest, symfony, delphi, upload

I want to realize a backup application that uploads large files (about 2GB) to a webserver (php symfony json) using REST-components of Delphi 10.2 Tokyo on the client side.
Alternaly I have to use ftp upload but than I send ftp credentials through the web.

Does somebody have an idea?

Comment: What have you tried so far? And why would using FTP send credentials over the Web? FTP does not work that way. And wouldn't you have to login to your REST server to allow uploading over HTTP? You do know that HTTP and FTP both have ways to secure sensitive login credentials, don't you? If FTP is an option, I would use that instead of REST.

Comment: With REST I have a one way solution, only to send data without being afraid that someboy can read them.

Comment: FTP is he same way. And like I said,. You can secure the data, using SSL/TLS. No benefit to using REST instead of FTP, except maybe for better firewall/NAT support.

Comment: I would prefer doing it with the port 443 because of the outgoing firewall. Do you have an idea to realize this via rest? I can send data via rest (till now about 5mb) but do not know how it works with 4gb data size. Can I get the current progress via rest?